# Payment methods disappear after zip was entered and country was changed?

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

**Magento 2.2.3**

I am having some trouble with my payment methods in the checkout. The methods are shown when the checkout loads. Now when I enter the address details, they are still shown.

When I change the country now, they disappear. I tracked this down a bit and noticed, that the factor which makes them disappear is the zip. As soon as the zip was entered and the country is changed, the methods disappear.

The country is allowed for payment methods, thats not the problem. Any idea where I might start looking?

I am using the iWays PayPal+ extension.

Thanks!

Comment: The most of Magento payment integrations have `Payment from Applicable Countries` and `Payment from Specific Countries` configuration options where availability of a payment solution for a specific country can be restricted because obviously not all payment integrations support all countries. I would suggest checking this configuration for your payment solution. Also, a payment integration uses a billing address to check if payment is available but by default, the billing is the same as a shipping address.

Comment: This is not the problem, the switching of the country and the payment methods work, until I enter the zip. After that everything stops working.